# why only one filename is written using ls redirect in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm building a shell script in my RedHatOS.

I tried to output filenames using the regular expression as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -1r rrr* > /tmp/memo.txt
```

and the contents of /tmp/meme.txt is this

```
/tmp/rrr1.txt
```

I want to write all files to the txt file like I did same thing in console

```
$ls -1r rrr* > /tmp/memo.txt
$cat /tmp/memo.txt
```

and the result of cat command is this

```
/tmp/rrr1.txt
/tmp/rrr2.txt
```

I don't understand what is happening.  Please tell me why this is occurring, and how to write all results of ls command to the file.

thanks.

Comment: I can't spot any obvious mistake, but could you try and see if this works?: `(for f in rrr*; do echo "$f"; done) > /tmp/memo.txt`

Comment: sorry I had mistake in writing this article. I want to use argument with full path.....

Comment: 1. That is not a regular expression, it's a file globbing pattern `rrr*`
 2. The -r switch does not use regular expression, it reverses the sort
 3. Because of #2, your command line (ls -1r rrr*) would not have given you the output you listed, it would have reversed the order, like so...

    $ ls -1r rrr*
    rrr2.txt
    rrr1.txt

Comment: This post is misleading. The OP was asking for a resolution of file globbing pattern inside the script when in reality the script is accepting parameters and the script is only evaluating `$1`. This post must be deleted or reworded to prevent misleading future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get the full path:

```
ls -d -1 $PWD/rrr*
```

Results:

```
/tmp/rrr1.txt
/tmp/rrr2.txt
/tmp/rrr3.txt
```

Also, with `ls -1r` you'll get

```
rrr3.txt
rrr2.txt
rrr1.txt
```

and using `ls -1` (without the `r`) gives you

```
rrr1.txt
rrr2.txt
rrr3.txt
```

And so your script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -d -1 $PWD/rrr* > /tmp/memo.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

thanks everyone.
now I've got an answer to output filenames in specific directory with using ls in bash script...

```
#!/bin/bash
data=("$(ls -trh "$@")")
for entry in "${data[@]}"
do
  echo "${entry}" > /tmp/memo.txt
done
```

you can get all filenames into text file(/tmp/memo.txt) by using this.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. The OP was asking for file globbing inside the script and this has nothing to do with it. And it unnecessarily used a variable and sub-shell.

Comment: Even more confusing is the fact that this answer was posted by the OP itself.